# Cursor is not changing when hovers on links while browsing in Kubuntu 13.04

Tags: firefox, kubuntu, google-chrome, kde, browser

Tested it in Chrome and Firefox - the cursor completely ignores the CSS `cursor` property on all sites, For example, on hovering over a link it appear as regular arrow. I am using the default KDE cursor theme (Oxygen).

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think I have the same issue. Chrome Ubuntu. No change when hovering over links sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on linux mint 13 - KDE..

You need to add the line:

```
gtk-cursor-theme-name="Oxygen_Blue"
```

to your ~/.gtkrc-2.0-kde4 file.